# Position ImageButtons in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I am trying to program a menu for a game and now a want to make the level selection. It should have three rows with 5 buttons per row.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<5; ++j){
            ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsBut = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            paramsBut.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            paramsBut.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

            int marginLeft = (int)((float)(sizeLeftWidth/6) * (j+1)) + j*buttonSize;
            int marginTop = (int)((float)(sizeLeftHeight/4) * (i+1)) + i*buttonSize;
            paramsBut.leftMargin = marginLeft;
            paramsBut.topMargin = marginTop;

            button.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            button.setMaxWidth(buttonSize);
            button.setMaxHeight(buttonSize);
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.level),buttonSize,buttonSize,false);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
            button.setImageDrawable(d);

            layout.addView(button,paramsBut);
        }
    }
```

RelativeLayout:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The problem is that the buttons are not at the right positions and I think the problem is with the margins.
Am I doing it right with the margins or is the whole code completely stupid? (I am always happy if I get hints how to improve my programming style ^^)

Answer (score 0):

I'd have used a simple xml file, instead of using `addRule()` function for `RelativeLayout`. Creating the whole `RelativeLayout` structure in java file is a pain and involves lots of coding, which would be easier to do in xml. You just need to make a xml for the same layout and use the following function to get the object of the `RelativeLayout` (If it's the root layout):

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout) View.inflate(R.layout.your_xml_here);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be initializing your UI through code, Android intends that you use layout files. For an example, you can create a file named "main.xml" inside the res/layout folder with the following XML code (notice the "ID" of the ImageButton is "myButton").

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/myButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:marginLeft="10dp" android:marginRight="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the onCreate method of your activity you call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

And you get a reference of your image button (ID is specified in XML):

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
btn.setBitmapImage(myImage); //you can use this
btn.setBitmapResouce(R.drawable.drawable_file); //or this
```

Also the purpose of RelativeLayouts is to specify where a view's position should be relative to another view, so you could use XML attributes like android:layout_below="@+id/viewId" and android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/viewId". Otherwise you can just use a LinearLayout, which should be a speed increase if a RelativeLayout isn't necessary.

Comment: ok I see that a LinearLayout would make more sense for my purposes but I dont think that an xml (i use them some thimes) will help. In the xml-file I have to drag and drop 15 buttons and then find them in code and change their attributes. The version with creating them in code is better or do I have a thinking mistake?

Comment: Once you get used to XML layout files it's actually a lot easier, and allows you to not use huge blocks of code to initialize your UI (specially with very large UIs). You can re-use XML layout files too, like if you were creating your own list adapter to populate a ListView with items that have your own custom layout.

Android definitely does **not** intend you to initialize UI from code.

Comment: Also, using XML makes sure your UI will work on all screen sizes. You shouldn't be using px for the width and height of views, you should be using dp (which automatically scales UI to the size they should be on different screens, from phones to tablets).

Answer (score 0):

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);    //<<---
```

this is what you need?

Comment: I didnt even realize that the layout was not centered. Now it is but the buttons are still at the false position, but I try to use the LinearLayout instead